# XMLHttpRequest.upload event overlapping?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I have written small application which take advantage of new [FILE API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/) and [FormData](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/05/formdata-interface-coming-to-firefox/) to upload the file.

I would like to be able to see how much time file uploading has taken. So I have used [`XMLHTTPRequest.upload`'s](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/XMLHttpRequest-2/#xmlhttprequestupload) events `loadstart` and `load` for starting the stopwatch and then stopping it when the file is loaded.

However when the file size of uploaded file is  small I have noticed that "load" event is fired before the `loadstart` event is complete(overlapping). So which is causing following execution sequence as shown in the below logs. You can see that the `stopWatch()` function is getting called before the `startWatch` is called causing error thrown.

They should be executing exclusively is what I was assuming till I saw this incident.

I am using the **FireFox 4Beta 6** version for this testing.

> 17:55:25 INFO - xhr loadstart = 0
> 17:55:26 INFO - xhr load = 0
> 17:55:26 INFO - percent = 100
> 17:55:26 INFO - _stopWatch()
> 17:55:26 INFO - xhr loadstart = end
> 17:55:26 INFO - _startWatch() = true

So I am confused as as per my thinking at any point in time only once JS statement can be in execution.

Also I am not sure if this is correct behavior? I mean load block's code executing before the loadstart's code block is executed. And if its right behaviour then how should i make sure that load event does not fire before the loadstart has not finished? To prevent the overlapping.